# Explanation & Example needed for PSObject variable setting and processing

Tags: powershell

The following code is used to output a table that shows what items are requiring the PC to need a restart. It basically compiles each type/reason for a restart and outputs the results.

My question is how is the line for `New-Object` setting the `RebootPending` object when there are multiple variables listed?

Questionable Line:

```
RebootPending=($CompPendRen -or $CBSRebootPend -or $WUAURebootReq -or $SCCM -or $PendFileRename)
```

Full snippet:

```
## Creating Custom PSObject and Select-Object Splat
$SelectSplat = @{
    Property=(
        'Computer',
        'CBServicing',
        'WindowsUpdate',
        'CCMClientSDK',
        'PendComputerRename',
        'PendFileRename',
        'PendFileRenVal',
        'RebootPending'
    )}
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Computer=$WMI_OS.CSName
    CBServicing=$CBSRebootPend
    WindowsUpdate=$WUAURebootReq
    CCMClientSDK=$SCCM
    PendComputerRename=$CompPendRen
    PendFileRename=$PendFileRename
    PendFileRenVal=$RegValuePFRO
    RebootPending=($CompPendRen -or $CBSRebootPend -or $WUAURebootReq -or $SCCM -or $PendFileRename)
} | Select-Object @SelectSplat
```

Bonus:

How do I use the `RebootPending` in an `if`/`else` to set the PowerShell error code to 1 if it is "True?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RebootPending=($CompPendRen -or $CBSRebootPend -or $WUAURebootReq -or $SCCM -or $PendFileRename)
```

That is setting the `bool` property by conditionally `OR`ing other variables.

Take a look at this example, showing how this conditional behavior works:

```
$Option1 = $true
$Option2 = $true
$Option3 = $true

$Result = $option1 -or $Option2 -or $Option3
$Result
# True

$Option1 = $false
$Option2 = $true
$Option3 = $false

$Result = $option1 -or $Option2 -or $Option3
$Result
# True

$Option1 = $false
$Option2 = $false
$Option3 = $false

$Result = $option1 -or $Option2 -or $Option3
$Result
# False
```

Comment: Keep in mind that these don't have to be boolean type. Using the comparison operator `-or` and  `-and` are converting the variables to bool. Strings and number will get evaluated as well.